# Can't make an edit text type password

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, passwords

I created a custom edit text, but something is weird, I can choose every input type for it except password type, I already try with input type TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD, TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD and also with transformationMethod PasswordTransformation(), rawInputType and with maxlines = 1 too! But nothing, I can set by code the text for my edit text and that appears in emulator as password format but when I focus to continue writing, all transforms to normal input type text. I don't know why. Someone can help me?

**SOLUTION**

I finally found the solution, the problem was that I put the attribute single line true, and it seems that password input type and transformation method only works with maxlines, so I have only to erase that and done. Thanks all!

Comment: Can you please provide your code? We can't help like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:inputType="textPassword"`:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/password"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="textPassword"
     tools:text="12345" />
```

Programatically:

```
password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Or:

```
password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/password"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:inputType="textPassword"
 tools:text="aaaaa" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I finally found the solution, the problem was that I put the attribute single line true, and it seems that password input type and transformation method only works with maxlines, so I have only to erase that and done. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Only change the éditent type input on XML file or JAVA file

**XML**

```
android:inputType="mySecret"
```

**JAVA**

```
password.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```